# execute a JApplet from another class?

Tags: java, applet

I'm new to Japplets.. I'm wondering if I have the following...

```
   classA A = new classA();
   //launch Japplet here
```

and `classA extends Japplet` how would I launch the Japplet?

If it's any help I'm using a Java Bean and I've tried calling `classA.init();` although this class does execute when I call this method it just doesn't show my JApplet on display.

Comment: Do you mean 1) on the same web page a browser is currently pointing to? 2) On a different web page? 3) Free floating outside the browser? 4) Something else?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the init() method?

Comment: When I do this `init()` does execute but the JApplet doesn't appear on screen.

Comment: Doesn't appear to be working.. I'm using a javabean if that's any help.. when I call `init()` it is executing it's just... not putting up the Japplet!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you either need to use a browser or an applet viewer to see anything.  During development I would recommend an applet viewer as it is easier to get going (fewer security issues).

Comment: How would I make an applet viewer Launch when I execute my class?

Comment: Just Google appletviewer - you will get plenty of information to start.  There is a default that comes with the JDK but there are others that you can download if you want.

Comment: Here is a quick, easy and simple example to get you started: http://www.roseindia.net/java/java-introduction/javatools/java_applet_viewer.shtml